# how to align a glyphicon to a form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm very sorry if this is just a simple question but I'm really bad when it comes to alignment/positioning of elements and stuff like that so here it goes.

My problem is shown here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy6XB.jpg

[image: picture of the issue]

I just want the glyphicon to appear beside the textfield not above it. Just that. I tried putting it inside the form tag but the result is the same. Here is my code.

```
<div id="form" class="collapse in">
        <div id="loginwrong" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <div id="loginwrong2" style="display: none;">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' style="color: red; font-size: 2em;"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">
            <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

I also have a script that will show the glyphicon if the password is wrong. (it's basically a password-accepting textfield)

```
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    $('#loginwrong2').show();
                </script>";
?>
```

Comment: You forgot the `?` in the ending PHP tag.

Comment: Oh I just wasn't able to paste it. I copied it from my code and my code has the ending ?> tag. Thanks for pointing it out though. Edited

Comment: Make a `span` out of `#loginwrong2`

Comment: is it about twitter-bootstrap or bootstrapping?

Comment: bootstrap like bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

From http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

```
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Input with success</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning2">Input with warning</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWarning2" aria-describedby="inputWarning2Status">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputWarning2Status" class="sr-only">(warning)</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError2">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError2" aria-describedby="inputError2Status">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputError2Status" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputGroupSuccess1">Input group with success</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGroupSuccess1" aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess1Status">
  </div>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputGroupSuccess1Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
</div>
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s8p0xyyc/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap, you should use bootstrap to design the form

```js
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#loginwrong2').show();</script>";
?>
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="row">   
  <div class="col-md-1">
                <span id="loginwrong2" class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' style="color: red; font-size: 2em; display:none;"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-11">
   <form method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">
            <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
  </div>  
 </div> 
</div>
```

PD: this is not a php question

Comment: I tried your answer but the glyphicon appears at the farthest left. I just want it beside the textfield. Thank you for giving me a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the right classes and move back the span with the incon inside the form

```
<div id="form" class="collapse in form-group  ">

        <form method="POST" class="form-inline  has-feedback" role="form">
            <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
             <span id="loginwrong2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red; font-size: 2em;"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: the glyphicon shows up already even though the user is not submitting anything yet. and the glyphicon appears at the farthest right

Comment: I left the ID property to let you hide it with `#loginwrong2{ display:none; }` and left the JS as is

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who answered! I got what I want by making a div for the glyphicon and a div for the form. Both divs has the display: inline-block in their styles.

```
<div id="form" class="collapse in">
        <div id="loginwrong" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <div id="loginwrong2" style="display: none;">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' style="color: red; font-size: 2em;"> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <form method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">
            <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There’s more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css make `<span id="loginwrong2">` `{position:absolute;left:12%;top:10%}`

See this 
http://www.bootply.com/BLgAr0zrLA